# How to show alert popup only inside specific screen using react native?

Tags: android, ios, typescript, react-native

In My case, I have implemented alert popup within a function and the function will call from `componentDidMount()`. Now the problem is the alert implemented inside the home screen but I am getting alert in other screen also. I want to show alert only when I am in home screen.

If user in other screen alert should not show.

My Code: (Home.tsx)

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    this.showAlert();
}

async showAlert() {

Alert.alert(
         ‘Hello’,
          [
            {
              text: "ok",
              onPress: () => {
             
              },
              style: 'cancel',
            },
            {
              text: "goodbye",
              onPress: () => {
                  this.props.navigation.navigate(‘details);
              },
            },
          ],
          { cancelable: false },
        );
}
```

Comment: Please give other details, do you have top or bottom navigation, and could you share the other code snippets

Comment: @TawandaMuzavazi I am having top navigation. Sorry, other snippets are not with me.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really possible / how alert was designed.  Instead I recommend using a Modal.